# How do you prove that a metric space $X$ is separable if and only if $X$ has a countable subset $Y$ with property below?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

A metric space $X$ is separable if and only if $X$ has a countable subset $Y$ with property: for $\epsilon > 0$ and every $x \in X$, there is a $y \in Y$ such that $d(x, y) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Why did you remove what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose that $Y$ is a countable set which is dense in $X$, then for any open Ball $U$ with $x\in U$, $U\cap Y\not=\emptyset$.
2. for any open set $U$, there exists an open Ball $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$, by the property, there is $y \in B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$, which shows that $Y$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: For any *non-empty* open set $U$...